# display a link in truncate smarty

Tags: smarty

In smarty we can use this to shorten the text output:

```
{$articleTitle}
{$articleTitle|truncate}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:""}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"---"}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"":true}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"...":true}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:'..':true:true}
```

the results will be like this:

```
Two Sisters Reunite after Eighteen Years at Checkout Counter.
Two Sisters Reunite after Eighteen Years at Checkout Counter.
Two Sisters Reunite after...
Two Sisters Reunite after
Two Sisters Reunite after---
Two Sisters Reunite after Eigh
Two Sisters Reunite after E...
Two Sisters Re..ckout Counter.
```

What I want to display is this : "`... <a href="{$url}">read more</a>`" 
when you apply it to the code, it would be something like this :

```
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"... <a href="{$url}">read more</a>":true}
```

but this does not work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to replace double-quotes with single-quotes within your message:

```
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"... <a href='{$url}'>read more</a>":true}
```

If it doesn't help, try to use additional variable for your message:

```
{assign var=readMoreText value="... <a href='{$url}'>read more</a>"}   
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:$readMoreText:true}
```